# Is it possible to get an image from a message and add it to a folder in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fs

Like is it possible to do something like `!image add [image file]` and then add the attachment to a folder? I think i can do that with fs, but i'm not sure how

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fs function [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options) or [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options). This function accepts the absolute path to a file to write to, and the data to write.  In your case, it should be a buffer or stream.

```js
// const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('./some_dir/some_file_name.extension', data);
```

To get the data in question, you should access [`Message#attachments()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments), a collection of all attachments on the message. Assuming you only want the first, you can use [`Collection#first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) to narrow down the results.

```js
const attachment = message.attachments.first();
if (!attachment) {
  // maybe place in some error handling
}
```

Unfortunately, the [`MessageAttachment`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) class *doesn't* actually hold a buffer/stream representing the attachment, only the URL leading to it. This means you'll need a third-party library such as [axios](https://npmjs.com/package/axios) or [node-fetch](https://npmjs.com/package/axios).

```js
// const fetch = require('node-fetch');
fetch(attachment.url)
  .then(res => res.buffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    fs.writeFileSync(`./images/${attachment.name}`, buffer);
  });
```

Make sure to validate that URL to make sure it's an image!

```js
if(!/\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/.test(attachment.url)) {
  // this attachment isn't an image!
  // we don't want to be downloading .exe files now, do we?
}
```

Finally, you should also be weary that if two files are named the same, such as `image.png`, trying to write the second one will overwrite the first. One way to overcome that issue is to add numerical suffixes to duplicates, such as `image.png`, `image-1.png`, `image-2.png`, etc. That could work out a little like this:

```js
fetch(attachment.url)
  .then(res => res.buffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    let path = `./images/${attachment.name}`;
    // increment the suffix every iteration until a file
    // by the same name cannot be found
    for (let count = 1; fs.existsSync(path); count++) {
      path = `./images/${attachment.name}-${count}`;
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(path, buffer);
  });
```

Comment: I tried it and i made it send a message after adding the image, but even if it sends it, the image isn't added to the directory, i tried with and without the file path and also tried changing writeFileSync to just writeFile, but didn't work

Comment: Ok it does add the attachments, but to the bot folder, while i want it to be in a "images folder", i tried adding the path but it still adds them to the bot folder, any idea?

Comment: it also gives a ```illegal operation on a directory``` error when i try to put a path

Comment: Oops! I put `attachment.name` as the path, which will always write to the root of your project, such as `image.png`. if you want to nest it into a directory, such as `images`, you can change it to `\`./images/${attachment.name}\``. "Illegal operation on a directory" means you passed in a directory for the path, not a file.

Comment: Thank you so much! everything works just fine, i also wondered, is it possible to do the same thing, but instead of adding a file, removing a file in that folder? anyway thanks again!

Comment: nvm i just had to remake the same code but using "unlinkSync" for removing the file

Comment: Glad I could help!